# Voltage on a disconnected part of the circuit?

Tags: voltage, transistors, digital-logic, logic-gates

[image]

Here's an RTL NAND Gate. I am trying to measure collector-emitter voltages of both transistors when both A and B are grounded. Transistor-A's collector voltage is about 3V. My multimeter reads C-E voltages of both transistors 0. So, my question is: If there's 3 volts on Transistor-A's collector and 0 volts on Transistor-B's emmiter, how come the potential difference of both "3V-TA's Emitter" and "TA's Emitter - 0V" is 0? I assumed an unconnected part's voltage would be 0 so i thought CE-A would be 3 Volts and CE-B would be 0 volts but it's obviously not the case. Also i realized that with some integrated circuits, Not applying a voltage to a pin, 0v or 5v, it acts as if i applied 5v to it anyway.
It may be a noob question but it's been bothering me for some time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Electronic peek-a-boo!**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3btV4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Open circuit switch loaded by voltmeter impedance.*

I think you are expecting about 1.5 V across TA and TB. If you redraw your circuit as open switches (transistor bases pulled to ground) it should become more obvious what's happening. The internal resistance of your meter is much lower than the "infinite" resistance of the other transistor switch. The voltmeter short-circuits TA leaving all the voltage across TB. As soon as you move the meter across TB it disappears there and appears across TA. It's electronic peek-a-boo!

If you look up your meter's impedance - probably 1M or 10M - and put that value resistor across the other transistor you should get half the voltage reading on your meter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, we can basically say that since there's no current across both voltmeter and the transistor to cause a voltage drop, the voltage on TA's collector is directly transferred to its emitter therefore it shows 0 voltage difference? and same thing happens with TB. So the middle doesn't have a "fixed" voltage like 0 as i presumed but whatever amount of voltage is on the other side of the voltmeter is transfered there due to having no current flow?

Comment: I think you've got it. If you like to imagine that both transistors have really low leakage - equivalent to, say, 100 MΩ - and you had a 1000 MΩ meter you might get half voltage at the mid-point. Your 1 MΩ meter is very low resistance in comparison so it shunts whichever transistor you try to monitor.

Comment: BTW, not leaving floating digital inputs is one of the very basic rules for a good digital design.

Comment: Thank you Claudio! I know that it's not a good idea. What i wanted to know was why it would act like a logic 1 instead of 0. I suppose it's simply indeterminable.